# Sendidng dynamic id and recieving data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm beginner at JS, AJAx, and so on. I was searching over the internet and found one code, so I used it, changed it a little... but it seems that it doesn't work (it does nothing).
First the javascript and html:

```js
function fetch_select(val)
{
   $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'fetch_data.php',
 data: {
   get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
   document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
 }

   });

}
```

```html
        <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
           <option>Wybierz</option>';
        $zapytanie = "
       SELECT
      scan_category.scat_id,
      scan_category.long_name
       FROM
      scan_category
       WHERE
      scan_category.state = 1 OR scan_category.state = 4 and scan_category.hide = 0
       ORDER BY
               scan_category.long_name";
              $wykonaj = mysql_query($zapytanie) or die(mysql_error());           
               while($row=mysql_fetch_array($wykonaj))
               {
                 echo '<option>'.$row[1].'</option>';
               }
               echo'</select>
               <div id="new_select">
               </div>';
```

```php
     $manga = $_POST['get_option'];
     $znajdz = "
        SELECT users.nick, scan_category.long_name, scan_work.work_name, scan_roles.role_id, scan_roles.scat_id, scan_roles.uid, scan_roles.what_id
        FROM scan_roles
        INNER JOIN scan_work ON scan_roles.what_id = scan_work.work_id
        INNER JOIN users ON scan_roles.uid = users.uid
        INNER JOIN scan_category ON scan_category.scat_id = scan_roles.scat_id
        WHERE
        scan_roles.scat_id = '$manga'";
     $wykonaj = mysql_query($znajdz or die(mysql_error());
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($znajdz)) {
           echo '<h2>'.$row[1].
           '</h2><br />'.$row[2].
           ':
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="manage.php5?mode=edit_role&edit&role_id="'.$row[4].
           ' method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="'.$_POST['pass'].
           '">';
           echo('<select name="user_id" size="1">');
           $zapytanie = '
                SELECT
                  users.uid,
                  users.nick
                FROM
                  users
                WHERE
                  active > 0
                 ORDER BY
                  users.nick';
           $wykonaj2 = mysql_query($zapytanie) or die(mysql_error());
           while ($wiersz = mysql_fetch_array($wykonaj)) {
             echo('<option value="'.$wiersz[0].
               '"');
             if ($wiersz[0] == $row[6]) echo ' selected="selected"';
             echo('>'.$wiersz[1].
               '</option>');
           }
           echo '</select>';

           echo('<input type="submit" value="edit">
        </form>');
```

Do you have any idea how to make it work (it doesn't seem to be even going to the file "fetch_data.php).

If I should add something else, tell me, I'm pretty much beginner!

When i put console.log(response) it does say ReferenceError: response is not defined, when i puted it like this - console.log("response") it gives me "response".

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console. Does it say anything?

Comment: oh, i didn't know there is something like this: ReferenceError: fetch_select is not defined

Comment: exactly. If there's a syntax error in the JavaScript code, the script doesn't even start

Comment: Oh, it means it's syntax error? I just copied this code from the other site... though it would work :O. From this site - http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/dynamic-select-option-menu-using-ajax-and-php.php

Comment: Sorry, more than syntax error it's a semantics error. It's telling you `fetch_select` function doesn't exist

Comment: Okay, I changed it a little, now it doesn't say anything and doesn't return anything.

Comment: put a console.log(response) on the Ajax callback and update your question adding what it is returned by php (console.log prints the string on the JavaScript console)

Comment: When i put console.log(response) it does say ReferenceError: response is not defined, when i puted it like this - console.log("response") it gives me "response". I should add on the question this info?